# How can I get width and height of grouped objects in Unity3D

Tags: unity

Is it possible to get height and width of grouped objects like this?

[image]

I tried boxcollider2d.bounds and renderer.bounds. Each shapes in the group has collider component.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Grab all the `.bounds` properties of all the items, and figure out what the maximum and minimum values are.

Comment: In my game, maybe there will be 100+ gameobject in group. Is this really good solution?

Comment: In that case, rethink your architecture if it needs this information.

Comment: Use [Bounds.Encapsulate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html).

Answer (score 1):

To get the bounds of a group of objects, you need to get the bounds of each object in the group. For each axis, you compare the maximum and minimum bounds of each object. The maximum of the local maximums is the global maximum, the minimum of the local minimums is the global minimum.

i.e.

```
 Global_X_Max = Max(item1.bounds.max.x, item2.bounds.max.x,...)
 Global_X_Min = Min(item1.bounds.min.x, item2.bounds.min.x,...)
```

Create new bounds using the 3 min values and 3 max values.

One way of implementing this is to use [`Bounds.Encapsulate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html), as [Chris](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/10563/chris-mcfarland) mentioned.

1. Create a new bounds instance
2. For each object, add their minimum and maximum bounds to the new bounds with [`Bounds.Encapsulate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html).
3. The resulting bounds object will contain all objects and their bounds. Retrieve the minimum and maximum from the new bounds object.

Even with 100+ items, this comparison is not too intensive if you're only updating it occasionally.